# Adobe air / air-android?

Tags: discussion, tags

Before things get out of hand, can someone advise whether [air-android](/questions/tagged/air-android) is a valid tag?

There are a bunch of edits from one particular user appearing in the review queue. My guess is he's finding all the [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [air](/questions/tagged/air) questions and adding yet another tag. There are only 26 or so 'air-android' questions at the moment, but if people keep approving these edits its quickly going to increase.

Comment: Tag appears to have been created 2 hours ago... perhaps someone is trying to get themselves the Taxonomist badge?

Comment: I'm kind of for `adobe-air-for-android` since it's separate from `adobe-air`.

Comment: I would assume Air for Android has its own unique set of issues, so personally I'm fine with it as a tag.  Whether the edits are appropriate is another question.

Comment: Damn you, Android and your fragmentation nonsense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a valid tag currently and sounds to me as if they're different enough to need different tags.

Answer (score 1):

[air](/questions/tagged/air) should be renamed to [adobe-air](/questions/tagged/adobe-air) in this process.

Comment: It's currently synonymed, which a pedant would argue is correct. (The 'A' in AIR already stands for Adobe)

Comment: We'll probably be OK, most questions about the gas we breathe are off-topic for Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: @PaulG air should be the synonym here, as the tag is much clearer if it is called adobe-air